# each() with multiple ids or classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form with 15 fields(including input types,select box,text area).

I can write a function to validate this form by the ordinary way,but thats not smart coding.I need to use each in this case.

This is what I was thinking:

```
$("#id1, #id2, #id3... #id15").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val == "") {
        $(this).closest("#error").css("display", "block");
    }
})
```

Should this validation be class based or id based,am I going the right way?Am i using each() in the right context?

Comment: Either will work, although a `class` would be more semantic for grouping. You are using `each` correctly.

Comment: Use the `required` attribute, it automatically prevents submitting empty fields (at least in modern browsers).

Comment: Are you validating all inputs in a particular parent?

Comment: val is a method call so needs () btw

Comment: Is your `#error` element unique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector here to select all the input elements inside the form like:

```
$("#formID :input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).closest("#error").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Or maybe add a specific class to all the inputs that you want to validate like `validate` and do like:

```
$(".validate").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).closest("#error").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

**Documentation:** http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

**Description:** Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Comment: as i said i have select box,text area alsoo..i know this solution..but i want to do it all in one single loop

Comment: @Onaseriousnote This is a single loop.

Comment: but this wont include select box,text area

Comment: @Onaseriousnote `:input` will select all form controls

Comment: @Onaseriousnote Note the difference between `input` and `:input`

Comment: dont have a form,instead i have a div...so should i replace the form in selector with div?

Answer (score 2):

Or any tag with id attribute inside the form

```
$('form *[id]')
```

or name attr would even better

```
$('form *[name]')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple inputs, selects and form elements, add a class like "input-group" to each element and then iterate over that group.

```
$("form .input-group").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val == "") {
        $(this).closest("#error").css("display", "block");
    }
})
```

Comment: -1 `$(this).val` isn't valid and this answer doesn't add anything new to the discussion.